# Responsive Webdesign for all the different devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend

I have about 5 years experience as a webdeveloper. But sometimes I have this question and I couldn't answer it on my self. There are sooo many devices nowadays with different screensolutions either in landscape & portrait and so on.

I still work with the Bootstrap breakpoints (1200px, 1024px, 768px, and for mobile i use 480px max-width) but recently I had some issues with my websites, because the customer is using as example a huawai or some smartphone that is not as popular as the iphone and the website was not optimized for this specific smartphone.

So how can i avoid something like that? Do you have any good tipps for me?

Comment: Responsive layouting should first and foremost mean making use of the space that is actually available, and not trying to target specific devices.

Answer (score 0):

Working for clients with multiple devices requirements could be a bit of a nightmare... What you could do in the future is ask your client to give you an specification of the application you are building and the targeted devices (even to the model).

I use the page below as a reference to build very specific media queries or as general as you want.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/#phone-queries

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to make some "fixes" for some devices.

One way to solve this would be to get the user agent:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

after this you could use regex or load them in an array to match the user agent or device:

user agents in array:

```
$mobile_agents = array('w3c ','acs-','and','so', 'on');
```

for devices:

```
$regex_match.= "htc|huawei";
```

now that the page can detect the user agent, the page also 
can give out specific stylesheets/media queries for devices.

This is a simple example in php and you can group devices and user agents as well.

Answer (score 0):

For truly responsive design, avoid using breakpoints to affect the style.  There are already too many possibilities, and far more on the way, for anyone to ever get it right.

About the only uses I've found for @media size queries are:

Test aspect ratio to determine whether it is in landscape or portrait mode.

```
@media (max-aspect-ratio 1/1) { ...
```

Test physical size to move buttons farther apart on small screens.

```
@media  screen and (max-width: 6in) {
    a { line-height: 200%; }  /* fat-finger clickables */
    input[type=radio] { margin: .5em; }
}
```

And of course, in all your CSS, remember to never use absolute units and to always use relative units (%, em, vh, vw).